# Access property before viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c

Inside the following method I am saving the current temp of a location, I want to be able to access the temp anywhere inside the class.

```
[_weatherAPI currentWeatherByCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude) withCallback:^(NSError *error, NSDictionary *result) {
    downloadCount++;
    if (downloadCount > 1)
        if (error) {
        }
    [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    self.tempLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f°",
                           [result[@"main"][@"temp"] floatValue] ];

    self.locationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                               result[@"name"]
                               ];
    self.summaryLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                              result[@"weather"][0][@"main"] ];

    [self setSaveTemp:result[@"main"][@"temp"]];


}];
```

I am then saving it to a property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *saveTemp;
```

And then saving it to this.

```
-(void)setSaveTemp:(NSString *)saveTemp {
_saveTemp = saveTemp;
}
```

In my viewDidLoad I am then calling everything

```
_weatherAPI = [[OWMWeatherAPI alloc] initWithAPIKey:@""];
[_weatherAPI setLangWithPreferedLanguage];
[_weatherAPI setTemperatureFormat:kOWMTempCelcius];

NSLog(@"%@", _saveTemp);
```

But this returns null as the viewDidLoad is getting called before the `_weatherAPI currentWeatherByCoordinate` what can I do to be able make _saveTemp not equal null but the actual value?

Comment: Time machine will be enough.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand?

Comment: If _saveTemp is not ready in viewDidLoad you can not do anything with it. You have to change application logic. For example process _saveTemp somewhere else and when it will be ready. For example you can call some [self displayTempMethod] from `_weatherAPI currentWeatherByCoordinate`

Answer (score 0):

I think this api will make server call and so it takes time to get the json data.
once json data is available, then it will execute callback block.

`saveTemp` variable will be initially `nil`, and you are setting it in completion block.

All you can do is just wait until the download is finished.And if you want to execute some method after download,then call that method in callBack block. so, that way your app can know that download is finished.